# Hosted Javascript framework

Tags: web-apps, framework

I'm doing a research for my graduation of BSc Software Engineer, and I'm exploring the possibilities to create a web version of the current complex windows application of my internship company. We create an application for theaters and cinemas to plan events and to sell and scan tickets, but the front-end is a classic Windows application. My research is mainly focused on how they can implement this into a web application. However, it is hard to find real good advice on the internet, because all te people comparing these frameworks are always biased to one of the sides. Also it's hard to compare their talking to the real world situation of the company. The company has only 3 fulltime developers, which have to maintain and further develop the back-end (ASP.NET), but also have to integrate the webapplication in the future. The technical requirements are:

- Should be hosted in Azure
- Should communicate with the current ASP.NET API
- Should be working on especially tablets
- Should be Single Page Application

The application requirements are:

- Login system
- Scanning barcodes or QR-codes
- High speed (especially during ticket-scan)
- Filling and submitting a form for new events
- Possibility for rebranding (different UI for different customercompanies)
- Security

I've looked into a lot of frameworks and ended up with Angular and Vue, but they seem quite similar. People say Vue is much easier to learn, so it's better for small teams. But they say Angular is better for more complex applications. Which framework fits these requirements?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that this site doesn't feature requests for product comparisions: SR is about suggesting specific software for specific needs you define. For details, see: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/185) So please [edit] your post (I've already started that for you to avoid your question being closed), list your requirements and ask for software meeting those, see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)